# Error when making AJAX POST request (xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null ))

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to refactor my code using AJAX and JQuery and have come unstuck at the first hurdle!

Basically what I'm working on is a blog and initially I had added a comments section which worked by redirecting to the 'show' page when a new comment is added. This was OK but I really want to refactor this into a 1-page process using AJAX and JQuery, particularly as I now want to add a function to edit comment and I do not want the user to be redirected to another form.

This is the form code to add a new comment:

```
<% if(currentUser){ %>
<div class = "container form">
   <form action = "/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/comments" method = "POST"nid="newComment">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img class="newComment-ico" src = "<%=currentUser.image%>">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <label for="comment">Add comment</label>
        </div>
    </div>
        <textarea class = "form-control" rows="4" placeholder = "Type comment here..." name = "comment[text]"></textarea>
        <button class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

<% } %>
```

Here is my POST route:

```
router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
// lookup blog using id
Blog.findById(req.params.id, function(err, blog){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/blogs");
    } else {
        // create new comment
        Comment.create(req.body.comment, function(err, comment){
            if(err) {
                req.flash("error", "Something went wrong");
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                if(req.xhr){
                    res.json(comment);
                } else {
                }
                comment.author.id = req.user._id;
                comment.author.username = req.user.username;
                comment.author.image = req.user.image;
                comment.save();
                // connect new comment to campground
                blog.comments.push(comment);
                blog.save();
                // redirect to campground show page
                req.flash("success", "Successfully added comment");
                res.redirect("/blogs/" + blog._id);
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

And here is my AJAX code:

```
$('#newComment').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var formData = $(this).serialize();
$.post("/", formData, function(data){
   console.log(data);
});
});
```

What I am getting is the following error when I dig into the Chrom dev tools having tried to run the code:

```
                // Do send the request (this may raise an exception)
                xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
            } catch ( e ) {
```

I've tried looking into this from other users' questions but as I've only just started to learn AJAX and I've fallen at the first hurdle a lot of it isn't making sense to me!

Here's the chrome log when I run the code:

https://bootcamp-dvbage.c9users.io/ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Please share the relevant logs (in your browser's developer tools' console).

Comment: Hi, just added it to the bottom of the initial post